# Problems with '._ElementUnicodeResult'

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, html-parsing, lxml, xml.etree

While trying to help another user out with some question, I ran into the following problem myself:

The object is to find the country of origin of a list of wines on the page. So we start with:

```
import requests
from lxml import etree

url = "https://www.winepeople.com.au/wines/Dry-Red/_/N-1z13zte"
res = requests.get(url)
content = res.content
res = requests.get(url)

tree = etree.fromstring(content, parser=etree.HTMLParser())
tree_struct = etree.ElementTree(tree)
```

Next, for reasons I'll get into in a separate question, I'm trying to compare the xpath of two elements with certain attributes. So:

```
wine = tree.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'row wine-attributes')]")
country = tree.xpath("//div/text()[contains(., 'Australia')]")
```

So far, so good. What are we dealing with here?

```
type(wine),type(country)
>> (list, list)
```

They are both lists. Let's check the type of the first element in each list:

```
type(wine[0]),type(country[0])
>> (lxml.etree._Element, lxml.etree._ElementUnicodeResult)
```

And this is where the problem starts. Because, as mentioned, I need to find the xpath of the first elements of the `wine` and `country` lists. And when I run:

```
tree_struct.getpath(wine[0])
```

The output is, as expected:

```
'/html/body/div[13]/div/div/div[2]/div[6]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]'
```

But with the other:

```
tree_struct.getpath(country[0])
```

The output is:

```
TypeError: Argument 'element' has incorrect type (expected 
       lxml.etree._Element, got lxml.etree._ElementUnicodeResult)
```

I couldn't find much information about `_ElementUnicodeResult)`, so what is it? And, more importantly, how do I fix the code so that I get an xpath for that node?

Comment: You're selecting a `text()` node instead of an element node; maybe try changing your xpath to: `country = tree.xpath("//div[contains(., 'Australia')]")`

Comment: Wow, it did work! `country[0]` is now `lxml.etree._Element`. And everything else went smoothly. If you have the time and energy, can you turn this into a proper answer so I can accept it and maybe you can explain the concepts underlying the problem and solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're selecting a `text()` node instead of an element node. This is why you end up with a `lxml.etree._ElementUnicodeResult` type instead of a `lxml.etree._Element` type.

Try changing your xpath to the following in order to select the `div` element instead of the `text()` child node of `div`...

```
country = tree.xpath("//div[contains(., 'Australia')]")
```